# File transfer socket programming

Tags: c#, .net

I making a file transfer program using C#. I have written both server and client programs. Now I want to do some additional things. I want to send a roll number (for example: 1,2,3 etc) of the user along with the IP address from client program which will be received at the server end. How will I do that? My sample client program code is given below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {    
            string roll ="1";
            string fileName = @"D:\demo.txt";
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234);
            Console.WriteLine("Connected. Sending file.");
            StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream());                
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
            sWriter.WriteLine(bytes.Length.ToString());
            sWriter.Flush();
            sWriter.WriteLine(fileName);
            sWriter.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine("Sending file");
            tcpClient.Client.SendFile(fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

What additional things will I need to add?

Comment: Create your own packets.

Comment: You need to concoct a protocol - ie a format in which to pass the data - then implement it

Comment: @Axs show your receiver code please.

Comment: Are the upvotes because _"Wow, cool, sockets"_? You need to do some research, and implement an application protocol.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a third-party library?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't existing protocols (ftp, http push, bits, ...) ? If you actually need to write yourself, why don't you host a WCF service with streams enabled (instead of working with raw sockets)?

Answer (score 1):

As the [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) suggests, `TCP` is only responsible for the `transport`/`session` level of the communication, in order to implement the full communication between your **client** and your **server** you need to define your own **applicative protocol** over your `TCP` communication.

For this you will need a few things:

- [Presentation Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_layer) which will be responsible for the `serialization`/`de-serialization` and `encryption`/`decryption` of the data -

  - For that you can use `BinaryFormatter` or write your own serializer, you can serialize to *Binary Data, XML, JSON or any other format you wish* but you should want to ***let a serializer handle this and not to do it in your applicative code as you just did***.
- `Application Layer` which will be responsible for the object representation of the data and allow you to abstractly change your data without changing your communication layers (used by implementing matching `objects` and `classes`)

  - Create a class for file representation that will contain:

    - File name.
    - File data.
    - Roll number.
    - *Any other applicative data as you wish.*

This way you will be able to create new message types if you need to without changing your whole model and design (like, *reset roll* message etc...).

Answer (score 0):

You can design a little protocol. Here is a basic example which can give an idea of how to start. Let's say we want to send a `float` value:

```
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(sWriter, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var floatValue = 23.4F;
    var bytes = new List<byte>();
    bytes.Add(0x03) // type of message: float
    bytes.Add(BitConverter.GetBytes(floatValue)); // 4 bytes of float
    writer.Write(bytes.ToArray());
}
```

And on the other side you would interpret the message like this:

```
switch (receivedArray[0])
    case 0x03: return BitConverter.ToSingle(receivedArray, 1);
               break;
```

However, you might want to support more type of data, maybe entire objects and so on. You might want to extend your supported data types, to introduce variable length strings, etc.

```
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(sWriter, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var bytes = new List<byte>();
    var floatValue = 23.4F;
    var ip = "192.168.111"
    var stringBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string);
    bytes.Add(0x03) // type of message: string
    bytes.Add(BitConverter.GetBytes(stringBytes.Length)); // 8 bytes with length
    bytes.AddRange(stringBytes); // entire string
    writer.Write(bytes.ToArray());
}
```

For advanced scenarios you should consider Protobuf or other serializing frameworks which makes it easier to use objects for dealing with data instead of raw floats and strings (this is suitable for industrial low level protocols like Modbus).